# Pyspark structured Streaming with kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run the spark structured streaming code reading from Kafka. On my structured stream I am doing a group by operation and trying to print the value like this-

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(APP_NAME). \
    master("local[*]"). \
    config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions",
           "java.security.auth.login.config=kafka-jaas.conf"). \
    getOrCreate()

log_ds_stream = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",
                                                        "rs3.internal.optimusride.com:6667"). \
    option("subscribe", "all-datasets"). \
    option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT"). \
    option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()

log_ds_stream = log_ds_stream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
log_ds_stream.printSchema()
log_count = log_ds_stream.groupBy("value").count()
query = log_count.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

but I am getting the following error-

> 2019-04-22 17:49:54 ERROR MicroBatchExecution:91 - Query [id =
>   a715ee42-f180-4730-81cf-956db3a866b2, runId =
>   1f90f58f-b121-4eac-abdc-1d8bff46fa0c] terminated with error
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError     at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.log(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.logDebug(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$ConfigUpdater.set(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:439)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:85)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
>   Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id =
>   a715ee42-f180-4730-81cf-956db3a866b2, runId =
>   1f90f58f-b121-4eac-abdc-1d8bff46fa0c]" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.log(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.logDebug(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$ConfigUpdater.set(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:439)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:85)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63,
>   in deco   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line
>   328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o61.awaitTermination. :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: null
>   === Streaming Query === Identifier: [id = a715ee42-f180-4730-81cf-956db3a866b2, runId =
>   1f90f58f-b121-4eac-abdc-1d8bff46fa0c] Current Committed Offsets: {}
>   Current Available Offsets: {}
>
> Current State: INITIALIZING Thread State: RUNNABLE    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
>   Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError  at
>   org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.log(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.logDebug(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$ConfigUpdater.set(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:439)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:85)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:265)
>     ... 1 more
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/job/sample.py", line
>   98, in 
>       read_msg_sstream()   File "/home/job/sample.py", line 92, in read_msg_sstream
>       query.awaitTermination()

I am unable to understand what can be the cause of this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What Spark version are you using? And what are the versions of spark-sql-kafka and kafka-client?

Comment: Yeah the spark version and the spark-sql-kafka version were different which was causing this issue.